# DRV8824 motor driver IC issue

Tags: design

We have use DRV8824 motor driver IC in our product.

We facing issue as per below,

1. motor not properly moved
2. motor jerky motion.

Please guide us[image]

Attached schematics and layout image.

enter image description here [image]

Comment: Welcome! Please show waveforms of VMA/VMB, AOUT1/2 and BOUT1/2

Comment: Use a TMC- more expensive but they are a bit smarter with their current. Usually jerky motion results when your rotor movement rate does not match up to what the current through the coils would cause.  This can make the next part of the pulse slow your rotor down or even move it back to where it was instead of forward to the next step.